# How to get the parameter from a relative URL string in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, parsing

What's the most efficient way to get a specific parameter from a relative URL string using C#?

For example, how would you get the value of the `ACTION` parameter from the following relative URL string:

```
string url = "/page/example?ACTION=data&FOO=test";
```

I have already tried using:

```
var myUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative);
String action = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("ACTION");
```

However, I get the following error:

> This operation is not supported for a relative URI.

Comment: Have you tried Request.QueryString["ACTION"]?

Comment: If you're using asp.net, use the [QueryString property on HttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: the URL string is coming from a database, not from the browser, so I don't think using HttpRequest would work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
 int idx = url.IndexOf('?');
 string query = idx >= 0 ? url.Substring(idx) : "";
 HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query).Get("ACTION");
```

Comment: Thanks, using the IndexOf and Substring worked. I haven't tried it with URIBuilder yet.

Comment: Second solution to use UriBuilder does NOT work for relative paths. It expects constructor parameter URL to have host. [UriBuilder help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y868d5wh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 9):

While many of the URI operations are unavailable for [`UriKind.Relative`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.urikind?view=netframework-4.7.2) (for whatever reason), you can build a fully qualified URI through one of the [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) that takes in a Base URI

Here's an example [from the docs on `Uri.Query`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.query?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```cs
Uri baseUri = new Uri ("http://www.contoso.com/");
Uri myUri = new Uri (baseUri, "catalog/shownew.htm?date=today");

Console.WriteLine(myUri.Query); // date=today
```

You can also get the current base from [`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.url?view=netframework-4.7.2) or even just create a mock URI base with `"http://localhost"` if all you care about is the path components.

So either of the following approaches should also return the QueryString from a relative path:

```cs
var path = "catalog/shownew.htm?date=today"
var query1 = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, path).Query;
var query2 = new Uri(new Uri("http://localhost"), path).Query;
```